# How to increment label by one every time a button is pressed?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, label, increment

Developing in Swift for iOS, I have created an array of Ints that I have labeled `amount`. Each Int in the array represents a total number for a specific item (first item in `amount` represensts total of cars, 2nd total of buses, 3rd bikes, and so on). Using a table view, I have placed a button and label inside of the table view cell. In the table view, I want the first cell's label to display the first Int in the `amount` , the second cell's label to display the second Int in `amount` , third cell's label to display third Int in the `amount`, and etc. I want it to function as follows, every time the button is touched up inside I want to corresponding label to increase it's display total by one. For example, if the button is tapped 7 times in the third cell, I want the third cell's label to display the Int 7. If the button is tapped 2 times in the fifth cell, I want the fifth cell's label to display the Int 2. What would be the best way to go about this and accomplish this?

```
@IBOutlet weak var flavorTable: UITableView!

//this is the array that I want to contain the Ints to display in each cell's label, 1st cell should display amount[0], 2nd cell amount[1], etc.
var amount = [Int]()


func bookieButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //this is where code that I want to increment the cell's label by one every time it is pressed but I'm unsure how to do so

 }


  public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FlavorCellTableViewCell


      return cell

}
```

Comment: This is not code writing service. You should show what you have tried and the issues you are facing !!! Please edit your question and post your attempt. You should take some time to read the site section https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also Apple's Swift book https://itunes.apple.com/tr/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4/id881256329?mt=11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can be done this way-:

I created a `dictionary` with `Integer` key and values as `[Int]`. To maintain the number of taps per `cell` per `button`, this `key` will be a cell `index` value, and `array` will hold total number of `tap` counts.

Point which is important in this case is  how to maintain previous `cell` tapped `count` data, so I maintained a `dictionary` for every `cell index` + I maintained few more checks , where i save previous `tapped index` in array , and if user taps the previously tapped `cell` again, I **fetch** saved **taps** from `dictionary` for particular cell index key, and update it back and save back to dictionary.

Check the code for better understanding, run and debug you will understand.

**Controller class-:** (Working code)

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // CELL DATA ARRAY

    var data = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    // DICTIONARY TO HOLD NUMBER OF TAPS PER INDEX as [Int] (having tapped index as unique key)

    var countDictionary = [Int:[Int]]()

    // Array to hold tapped cell index

    var indexs  = [Int]()

    // Initial tap count

    var numberOfTapsPerCell : Int = 0

    // This is the array given to dictionary as value(it has tapped count per cell)

    var totalTaps = [Int]()

    //MARK-: VIEW DID LOAD

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // INITIALIZE total tap ARRAY WITH INDEX 0

        totalTaps = Array(repeating: 0, count: 1)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

// TABLE VIEW METHODS

extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    // NUMBER OF ROWS
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    // number of sections
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    // Cell for row

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // deque cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.customLabel.text = "Total taps : \(String(data[indexPath.row]))"
        // CALL BACK BUTTON 

        cell.readCount = { [weak self] cell in

            // Get index path of tapped cell

            let index = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)

            // Variable that holds previously tapped counts fetched from dictionary

            var previousCountIncrement = 0

              /* This loop checks if user is tapping new cell or previously tapped cell. If he taps new cell we re-initialize numberOfTapsPerCell to 0 (else lock) ,else we fetch value from dictionary for particular row , and increment previous value by 1 and save back in dictionary(if block) */

            for selectedIndex in (self?.indexs)!{

                if selectedIndex == index?.row{
                    let previousIndexCount = self?.countDictionary[selectedIndex]
                    for numberSum in previousIndexCount!{
                        previousCountIncrement = numberSum
                        previousCountIncrement += 1
                        cell.customLabel.text = "Total taps : \(String(previousCountIncrement))"
                        self?.data[selectedIndex] = previousCountIncrement
                        self?.totalTaps[0] = previousCountIncrement
                        self?.countDictionary[selectedIndex] = self?.totalTaps
                        return

                    }

                }else{

                    self?.numberOfTapsPerCell = 0
                }
            }

            /* Here we are saving tapped cell index in array. This is the code block which is always called once for each cell */

            if let row = index?.row{
                self?.indexs.append(row)
                self?.numberOfTapsPerCell += 1
                self?.totalTaps[0] = (self?.numberOfTapsPerCell)!
                self?.countDictionary[row] = self?.totalTaps
                let dict = self?.countDictionary[row]
                for value in dict!{
                cell.customLabel.text = "Total taps : \(String(value))"
                self?.data[row] = value
                }

            }

        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Custom Cell** class-:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var customCount: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var customLabel: UILabel!

    // Call back function


    var readCount : ((CustomCell)->())?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    // Cell button action

    @IBAction func countTaps(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let count = readCount{
            count(self)
        }

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Hope that helps you, let me know if any issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.2

```
var incrementOrDecrementValue = 0
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

@IBAction func increaseButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    incrementOrDecrementValue += 1;
    self.label.text = "\(incrementOrDecrementValue)"
}

@IBAction func decreaseButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    if(incrementOrDecrementValue != 0){
        incrementOrDecrementValue -= 1;
    }
    self.label.text = "\(incrementOrDecrementValue)"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way should be, add tag on each button inside tableView: cellForRowAt:indexPath: method. You can set tag same as indexPath.row.

Now from bookieButton: method, check what is the tag value for that sender. So the tag value is same as indexPath.row. Now update that row with updated value in your count Label.

You can use the follwing code to update a signle row,

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowNumber, inSection: 0)
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
```

Comment: It is not possible to connect a button to repeated content. OP would need to subclass a table view cell and connect the button to it.

Comment: He will set tag once...not repeated time. Cell identifier should be like @"Cell%d",indexPath.row. Yeah subclass is also another approach, for that he need to create his customCellDelegate. I do not know why you give negetive in my answer. This approach is also valid.

Comment: Cell identifier should be like @"Cell%d",indexPath.row. So each row will have separate identifer and will create once with specific tag.

Answer (score -1):

you should write the following code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    let row = indexPath.row
    if(row < self.amount.count)
    {
        self.amount[row] += 1
        tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .none)

    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! FlavorCellTableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row
    if(row < self.amount.count)
    {
        cell.countText = "\(self.amount[row])"

    }


    return cell
}
```